# string option to string conversion

Tags: type-conversion, ocaml

How do I convert the string option data type to string in Ocaml?

```
let function1 data = 
  match data with
   None -> ""
   | Some str -> str
```

Is my implementation error free? Here 'data' has a value of type `string option`.

Comment: Sure. You can test it on a few values including `None` and `Some("foo")` if you want to make sure.

Comment: Depends on what you mean by error free.  It contains no obvious errors in this context, but if something that uses it and barfs on the empty string(or expects a different choice in the face of None) then it is obviously broken.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To answer your question, yes.

For this simple function, you can easily find it in `Option` module. For example, `Option.default` totally fits your purpose:

```
let get_string data = 
    Option.default "" data
```

There are many other useful functions for working with option types in that [module](http://ocaml-lib.sourceforge.net/doc/Option.html), you should check them out to avoid redefine unnecessary functions.

Comment: Note that Option is only available in ExtLib, and is not provided in the standard library.

Comment: Thank you all! I just figured out that the error is somewhere else. But I indeed learned something new regarding options module.

Comment: `default` is now in `BatOption` (batteries package). See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9914219/where-can-i-find-the-ocaml-option-module).

Answer (score 3):

Another point is that the compiler would tell you if there's something wrong.  If the compiler doesn't complain, you know that the types all make sense and that you have covered every case in your `match` expression.  The OCaml type system is exceptionally good at finding problems while staying out of your way.   Note that you haven't had to define any types yourself in this small example--the compiler will infer that the type of `data` is `string option`.

A lot of the problems the compiler can't detect are ones that we can't detect either.  We can't tell whether mapping `None` to the empty string is what you really wanted to do, though it seems very sensible.

Comment: Thank you all! I just figured out that the error is somewhere else. But I indeed learned something new regarding options module.