# Where can I find the OCaml Option module?

Tags: module, functional-programming, ocaml

I mean this module : [Option](http://ocaml-lib.sourceforge.net/doc/Option.html)

I can't find it, `open Option` gives me `Error: Unbound module Option` and there is no 'option.cma' file

Is it in the standard library ? Is it named 'option.cma' ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is not part of the OCaml standard library, no.  It looks like it might be part of a former library named Extlib.  Extlib, in turn, seems to have become part of [OCaml Batteries Included](http://batteries.forge.ocamlcore.org/).  The Option module is now named [BatOption](http://ocaml-batteries-team.github.com/batteries-included/hdoc/BatOption.html).

If you want this module, you should get OCaml Batteries Included.  Then you need to tell the  OCaml compiler how to find the library.  It will be explained in the installation instructions for Batteries.

Comment: thanks for the answer, didn't know Batteries; Is this lib designed to be the next standard library, some sort of Boost for ocaml?

Comment: As I understand it, it's not intended to be a standard part of the OCaml distribution.  But this is good, it means that it can be improved independently of the compiler itself.  It's intended to be *a* standard, I guess you could say.  It seems to have good acceptance among OCaml coders.

Comment: Batteries and Jane Street's Core are the two libraries currently considered to be the main "standard" libraries for OCaml. However both are distributed separately from ocaml itself. ExtLib is no longer recommended since Batteries has absorbed it fully.

Comment: Is there a way to get the Option library without using Batteries? Like, can I write `opam install (something)` to get it?